RMarkdown: YAML hearder not changing font as desired
I am knitting a pdf with R-Markdown and my PDF does not seem to be taking to the desired font (Noto) as emojis and other less common characters are still coming out as 
Note: I need both PDF and HTML on the header.
always_allow_html: yes
header-includes:
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{NotoSans-Regular}[Path=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/NotoSans/, Extension=.ttf]
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{colortbl}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \usepackage{tabu}
  \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
output:
  pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
      template: eisvogel
      toc: true
      number_sections: true
  html_document:
      toc: true
      number_sections: true
      toc_float: true
      theme: united 


A good way to get emoji support in LaTeX is to define a fallback font:
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{luaotfload}
  \directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback("mainfontfallback",{
      "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf"
  })}
  \setmainfont[RawFeature={fallback=mainfontfallback}]{NotoSans}
output:
  pdf_document:
      latex_engine: lualatex

Note that we needed to switch the LaTeX engine to lualatex, as XeLaTeX doesn't support this feature.
